# How can the caller's process be identified in an ATL COM+ out-of-proc server application?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an ATL service running as an out-of-proc server that has several COM classes that the clients are expected to be using.  Because of a change in requirements, I need to be able to identify which process owns which instances of the objects.  I'm trying to use some of the COM functions to find out this information but I can't find the right ones.  `CoGetCallContext` only returns information about the user who called the method, not which process it came from.  Same with `CoQueryClientBlanket`.  What function can I use to find out this information?

Comment: [Determine the Process ID of the Client Process communicating with a COM RPC Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770684/determine-the-process-id-of-the-client-process-communicating-with-a-com-rpc-serv)

Comment: Thanks @RomanR., I thought it might be here but I didn't see it before.

Comment: You best bet is changing the interfaces so that when an object is being created the caller passes his id.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm 6.5 years late but just answering this in case anyone in the future needed it.

So there's a way to do this.... but through a private built-in COM interface, which is `ICallingProcessInfo`

Interface definition:

```cpp
MIDL_INTERFACE("68C6A1B9-DE39-42C3-8D28-BF40A5126541")
ICallingProcessInfo : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual STDMETHOD(OpenCallerProcessHandle)(DWORD dwDesiredAccess, HANDLE* handle) = 0;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
HANDLE handle;
ComPtr<ICallingProcessInfo> callingProcessInfo; // ComPtr is from WRL, you can use the interface directly instead
CoGetCallContext(__uuidof(ICallingProcessInfo), (void**)callingProcessInfo.GetAddressOf());
callingProcessInfo->OpenCallerProcessHandle(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &handle);
```

I tested this on a WinRT OOP Server but since WinRT Servers are just COM Servers it should work with normal COM Servers too

Comment: Thanks! Although I've long since moved on from this project, hopefully it will be helpful to others in the future :-D